# Is it possible to cover a chess board that is missing its corners with only L-Shapes?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, tiling, chessboard

Question: An $8$ X $8$ chess board is missing its corners. Can you completely cover the chess board with L-shapes resembling the way a knight can move, i.e., shapes that look like this:$\begin{matrix}X&X&X\\X \end{matrix} $ in any orientation ?

I don't even really know where to begin with discrete math problems like this. I would appreciate any tips, hints, or answers to this question. Thanks.

Comment: The classic way to solve a problem like this is to find a coloring of the chessboard such that the count of squares on the board with each color is different, but the piece must cover an equal number of squares of each color. Here you can do something similar — you can color the chessboard with two colors such that the L in any orientation always takes two squares more of one color than of the other, but the board has an equal number of squares of each color. (Note that this isn't necessarily the 'usual' coloring of the squares.) Can you see why this would make the tiling impossible?

Comment: @StevenStadnicki So for a regular 8 X 8 grid, you can fill it with those L shaped blocks, then there are some colorings that allow for the L to cover the same amount of colors. There are also some orientations of the L shapes that don't allow for the standard 8 X 8 grid to be filled, so there are some colorings that don't allow the L to cover the same amount of colors. Is this kind of the idea?

Comment: No, you have missed the point that the coloring is not the usual chessboard coloring.  In the new coloring no matter how you position the $L$ it covers three of one color and one of the other.  There are $60$ squares in the chessboard with no corners, so you need $15 L$ tetrominos.  These will cover two (or six ...) more squares of one color than the other, but the board has the same number of each color.

Comment: @RossMillikan Sorry. I wish I could say I'm following, but I'm just having trouble visualizing what this means. Are the tetrominos colored, and when placed give a new coloring of the chess board?

Comment: Suppose every square on an odd-numbered row is colored pink, and every square on an eveN numbered row is colored purple. Can you see that an L-tetromino is always going to cover $3$ squares of one color and $1$ square of the other color? Either $3$ pinks and $1$ purple, or else $3$ purples and $1$ pink?

Comment: By the way the same argument will work for an $m\times n$ chessboard with its $4$ corner squares removed (so $m,n\ge2$) if $mn$ is divisible by $8$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Color the board this way.  Note that wherever you place an L tetromino it covers three white squares and one orange, or one white and three orange.  If you cut off the four corners, you have $30$ of each color.  To match the area you need $15$ tetrominos.  They cannot cover an equal number of squares of each color, so the tiling is impossible.
[image]